# Hide or show LI based on the category that is selected (filter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, categories

I have a list of li items whose categories have been added to the class. 1 means it is associated with that category, 0 means it is not. When first visiting the page, they will all appear "View All". Clicking "Fruits" will show all items that have "fruits-1" in them. Clicking "View All" will show ALL items.

Filter by:

```
<ul class="categories">
<li><a href="">View All</a></li>
<li><a href="">Fruits</a></li>
<li><a href="">Vegetables</a></li>
<li><a href="">Super Smoothies</a></li>
<li><a href="">Coffee and Tee</a></li>
<li><a href="">Nuts</a></li>
<li><a href="">Desserts & Cakes</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="items">
<li class="fruits-0 vegetables-1 super-1 coffee-0 nuts-1 desserts-1">Product 1</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-0 nuts-0 desserts-0">Product 2</li>
<li class="fruits-0 vegetables-1 super-1 coffee-0 nuts-0 desserts-1">Product 3</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-0 nuts-0 desserts-0">Product 4</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-0 nuts-1 desserts-0">Product 5</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-1 nuts-1 desserts-0">Product 6</li>
<li class="fruits-0 vegetables-1 super-0 coffee-1 nuts-1 desserts-0">Product 7</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-0 nuts-1 desserts-0">Product 8</li>
</ul>
```

I currently have this. However, it is not working on Categories that have a space in them, but the & is working. How can I get it to work for categories with a space in them as well e.g. Super Smoothies?

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.categories li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split("&");

        if (category[0] == "view all") {
            $('ul.items li').show();
        } else {
            //hide all categories
            $('ul.items li').hide();
            $.each(category, function (i, v) {
                $('ul.items li.' + v.trim() + "-1").show();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your script would also show `<li class="cakes-1">...</li>` if you click on "Desserts & Cakes"

Comment: [`String.prototype.split([separator[, limit]]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - _separator_: Optional. Specifies the character **(s)** to use for separating the string.

Comment: I know it works for Desserts & Cakes, but it is not working for Super Soothies?

Comment: How do I make it work for Super Soothies? What do I change this code to?
 var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split("&");

Comment: You didn't read my first comment carefully. And the link of the second is also "untouched" otherwise you would have read the documentation for `.split()` which has all the infos you need. Just specify the characters (plural) you want to split the string at.

Comment: Sorry I do not know any javascript :( What would my code need to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `split(" ")` instead of `split("&")` and change view all condition like below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.categories li a').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(" ");//changes
        if (category[0] == "view" && category[1] == "all") {//changes
            $('ul.items li').show();
        } else {
            //hide all categories
            $('ul.items li').hide();
            $.each(category, function (i, v) {
                $('ul.items li.' + v.trim() + "-1").show();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
<li><a href="">View All</a></li>
<li><a href="">Fruits</a></li>
<li><a href="">Vegetables</a></li>
<li><a href="">Super Smoothies</a></li>
<li><a href="">Coffee and Tee</a></li>
<li><a href="">Nuts</a></li>
<li><a href="">Desserts & Cakes</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="items">
<li class="fruits-0 vegetables-1 super-1 coffee-0 nuts-1 desserts-1">Product 1</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-0 nuts-0 desserts-0">Product 2</li>
<li class="fruits-0 vegetables-1 super-1 coffee-0 nuts-0 desserts-1">Product 3</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-0 nuts-0 desserts-0">Product 4</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-0 nuts-1 desserts-0">Product 5</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-1 nuts-1 desserts-0">Product 6</li>
<li class="fruits-0 vegetables-1 super-0 coffee-1 nuts-1 desserts-0">Product 7</li>
<li class="fruits-1 vegetables-0 super-0 coffee-0 nuts-1 desserts-0">Product 8</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this will help you :)